# What are references for Rama's abode in Vaikuntha region?

Tags: rama, lokas

Ramanandi sect believes that Rama has a planet in Vaikuntha called Sakethloka.
Are there any scriptural references for this loka?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are references of Saketa AKA Ayodhya in scriptures:

The Shiva Samhita mentions there are two Ayodhyas- Para-Ayodhya which exists outside the material universe and the Ayodhya on Earth where Sri Rama descended:

> **The Para-Ayodhya is where Bhagavan disports** while Ayodhya on the Earth is where Bhagavan indulges in divine play. Bhagavan Sri Rama is the Supreme Lord of both these Lokas. **Whatever is present in Para-Ayodhya is also present in the Ayodhya on the Earth.** (**Shiva Samhita, Canto V, Chapter II**)

The Vashishtha Samhita states that Saketa-Loka encompasses all the Lokas situated outside the material universe:

> **Saketa-Loka is itself a form of Truth, Consciousness, Supreme Bliss. All the abodes of Vishnu and Goloka are a part of the eternal Saketa-Loka.** (**Vashistha Samhita**)

Lastly, in the Padma Purana, it is described that Ayodhya lies on the centre of Vaikuntha:

> Beyond these Lokas lie the Supreme abode of Vishnu. The devotees and servants of the Lord resides in this Supreme abode of Bhagavan Vishnu, the very embodiment and bestower of Supreme Bliss. At the very centre of this Loka, **is situated, the divine city by the name of "Ayodhya"**, which is adorned and filled all around by beautiful and magnificent structures. (**Padma Purana 6.228.10-12**)

Comment: I didn't find any Canto 5 in Shiva Samhita, can you provide archive link..

Comment: @MohMur See: http://lordrama.co.in/saket-loka.html

Answer (score 0):

**ॐ याऽयोध्या सा सर्वबैकुण्ठानामेव मूलाधारा प्रकृतेः परा तत्सद् ब्रह्ममयी विरजोत्तरा दिव्यरत्नकोशाढ्या तस्या नित्यमेव श्रीसीतारामयोर्विहारस्थलमस्ति।।**

(इति अथर्ववेदे उत्तरार्द्ध रामरहस्य उपनिषद उत्तरखंड)

प्रकृति से परात्पर, सत्यस्वरूप, ब्रह्ममयी जो ***अयोध्या है वह समस्त वैकुण्ठ लोकों की भी मूलाधार*** है। इसके उत्तर में विरजा आदि नदियां प्रकाशित होती है और दिव्य रत्नों से मण्डित कोश (मण्डप) में नित्यरूप से श्रीसीताराम जी की विहार स्थली विद्यमान है।

***Ayodhya, which is beyond nature, true form, Brahmamayi, is also the foundation of all the Vaikunth worlds***. Rivers like Virja etc. are illuminated in its north and Shri Sitaram ji's place of residence is constantly present in the kosh (mandap) decorated with divine gems.

**तदेव त्रिपाद् विभुति वैकुंठ स्थानम्।
तदेव परम साकेत महाकैवल्यम्।।**

Tripadvibhuti maha narayan upanishad

यह साकेत लोक (नित्य अयोध्या धाम) त्रिपाद विभूति परम वैकुंठ है (क्योंकि यह सभी वैकुंठों की नींव/मुल है)

This Saket Lok (Nitya Ayodhya Dham) Tripada Vibhuti is Param Vaikunth (because it is the foundation of all Vaikunths).

Comment: Many times, we have notified you to use proper formatting in your answer. Please consider learning how to format your post from [help](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help) section and edit your answers. Also you didn't mention chapter and verse number you have added from Tripadvibhuti maha narayan upanishad. Please add that too.